# Python - How to find which condition is true in if statement?

Tags: python

I have an if statement has many conditions, for example:

```
if(0 > 1 or 9 < 10 or 2 == 1):
       print('Hello World!')
```

so i wanna know which is the right condition that let the if statement continues to print hello world? "without using another if statement or elif"

In my code I have lots of conditions so it's difficult to use a lot of else statements to just know what is the right condition was.

Comment: one way to do it would be to create boolean variables. So following your example:
`is_0_greater_than_1 = 0 > 1`, `is_9_lower_than_10 = 9 < 10`, `is_2_equal_1 = 2 == 1`. And then, you can print those variable to know which one is `True` and makes the `if` statement `True`

Comment: You can't without some other means. There is no built-in way to know which term of a condition was true. You need to do a manual check.

Comment: @dallonsi that's helpful thx!

Comment: If you have to do something according to the 3 partial results, it may be usefull to do it directly with 3 different if ?

Comment: @Malo that's just an example, I said after that that I have a lot of conditions, in fact I might add more later, so I have to use a lot of if statement. The idea of my question is how to check all conditions without making many if statements. I might asked a wrong question in first place so ppl got me wrong.

Comment: @Jawad ok, but as you have many different answers already, it would be interesting to know if you have a real practical example, so we can see the use of this, and maybee propose something more efficient.

Comment: @Malo yes I do actually, but it's private code. I'm making a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's impossible - each condition is evaluated, we can only get a result.

However, if instead of `or`s, we have them stored* in a list like this:

```
conditions = [0>1, 9<10, 2==1] # it gets evaluated here!*
if any(conditions):
   print('Hello World!')
```

we could get the index of the True element by doing `conditions.index(True)`.

[*] But be aware that `conditions` doesn't consist of pure conditions but of `True`s and `False`s because *they got evaluated*. That's why I said it's impossible to get the *condition* itself.

Comment: Python supports short circuiting. In an if-statement, they are not necessarily evaluated all.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's not what I meant when I said they got evaluated. I meant that you can't get the condition back from it which seemed to be OPs intention. Your example calculates conditions eagerly too but in separate variables instead of a list.

Comment: Ok, got it. Seems I misread the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

For hard coded conditions like in your example, a good IDE should have an indicator and propose that you simplify the condition.

If you have variables in the condition, this will of course not be possible. In such a case, I would refactor the code and introduce additional semantics by using a variable name for the individual boolean parts of the condition.

In [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> extracts a condition into a variable.

A more realistic example (before):

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, age, totalsales, paymenttype):
        self.age = age
        self.totalsales = totalsales
        self.paymenttype = paymenttype


c = Customer(21, 3000, 2)
if c.age > 18 or c.totalsales > 5000 or c.paymenttype == 1:
    print('Hello World!')
```

After:

```
c = Customer(21, 3000, 2)
is_adult = c.age > 18
is_vip = c.totalsales > 5000
is_payed_in_advance = c.paymenttype == 1
if is_adult or is_vip or is_payed_in_advance:
    print('Hello World!')
```

When you reach the if-statement, you can inspect each part of the condition in the debugger.

[image: Mouse hover in debugger]

Note that this may change the behavior of your program, because with the changed code, each condition is evaluated, whereas [short circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) may have been applied before. However, I never ran into a situation where this caused a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Chained boolean expressions will be evaluated from left to right. If one of the chained statements is evaluated as being `True`, the remaining conditions will not be checked.

Assuming `second_condition` is fulfilled and hence will be evaluated as `True`, the following pseudo-code snipped would evaluate `first_condition` as `False` and then enter the `if` statement because of `second_condition` being `True`. However, `third_condition` will not be checked as another check before was already evaluated as `True` and thus the complete statement will become `True`:

```
if (first_condition or second_condition or third_condition):
    pass
```

Knowing which condition was evaluated as `True` is not possible with the approach shown above. Therefore, I would suggest rewriting your checks as follows:

```
def handle_true(condition):
    pass


if first_condition:
    handle_true('first')
elif second_condition:
    handle_true('second')
elif third_condition:
    handle_true('third')
else:
    pass
```

The `if`/`elif` will be evaluated in the same way as your chained `or` expression. If one condition fails, the next will be checked. If one of the given conditions is evaluated as `True` the branch will be entered. If none of the given conditions is fulfilled, the default `else` will be entered.

Combining this with the small helper function `handle_true()` should do the trick and not only provide a way to check which condition fired, but also provide a single place for handling any `True` condition.

Comment: `handle_true` will only ever get called with `condition = True`

Comment: @RoyCohen: You are definitely right. As OP stated " just know what is the right condition", I assumed that we are interested in fulfilled conditions only.

Comment: OP's question was ambiguous, I'm not really sure what he ment. But `handle_true` doesn't need a parameter if that parameter's value is always gonna be the same.

Comment: This is limited to `or` conditions. While that fits the code of OP, OP also said "I have many conditions" - which might not be `or` only. So IMHO this approach is of limited use.

Comment: @RoyCohen: Ohh, just missed this design flaw in my code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @albert Just saw the editted answer, great answer! Just wanted to point out this is where the new match/case feature will come is handy (python 3.10 prerelease), also check out [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would ever want to use this but okay...
You need to return a value which has a special `__bool__` so I would define a class.
The class will have one instance variable, `index` to indecate the first `True` condition, or `None` if there's no `True` condition.
The `__bool__` function then only needs to check whether `index` is `None`:

```py
class Any:
    def __init__(self, *conditions):
        self.index = None
        for i, cond in enumerate(conditions):
            if cond:
                self.index = i
                break
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.index is not None
```

Example usage:

```
if o := Any(0 > 1, 9 < 10, 2 == 1):
       print(f'The index of the first True condition is {o.index}')
```

Comment: This is limited to `or` conditions. While that fits the code of OP, OP also said "I have many conditions" - which might not be `or` only. So IMHO this approach is of limited use.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You're correct, it is limited. I think I misunderstood the question because the accepted answer has nothing to do with finding the index of the first condition to evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good option will be to create a list of condition and to check you the item of your list in a loop.

```
cond=[True, False, True, 5>10,True,False,1==1,3<-1,'a' == 'a'] # assume this is your list
for i in range(len(cond)):
    if cond[i]:
         print(i) # will return the Item adress correspending to True
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do:
`print(0 > 1) print(9 < 10)`
It will print `true` or `false`